# Adding an image to the minicart in 1.9

Tags: checkout, ce-1.9.0.1, rwd, rwd-theme

I am using Magento 1.9 and am required to add an image to the minicart underneath the sub total section, I am working as an apprentice so I'm pretty new to all of this, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: are you find mini car file??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you minicart file location `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart/minicart.phtml`(if you  have using rwd as your design package)
Here you need to image.